# NotImplementedError: Conversion 'py2rpy' not defined for objects of type '<class 'str'>'

Tags: python, r, plotly-dash, rpy2

I'm building a `Plotly` Dash in Python and I need to use the rpy2 package to import some functions not supported in Python, so I get this error when I call `(%R-i df)` in the dash,

The strange thing is that the R code works fine outside the dash, but with it it cannot totally implement any code of R.

I tried all the solutions linked below, but it's not working. Any ideas?

https://github.com/theislab/anndata2ri/issues/50
https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/pandas.html

Comment: It would be a lot more helpful if you included the code. Sharing Python and R objects, like data frames, arrays, matrices, and plots, tends to work great. Sharing functions, not so much. Use the function in R in R, and bring the modified data into Python. Another possibility is rendering what you're looking for without Dash. I haven't come across anything that Dash offers that I can't do with R and Javascript. I haven't come across the need to do that for Python, yet. However, if you can do it in R, I'm like 99.99999% sure that you can do it in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the r context within your Dash/Plotly plot function - the one with the callback updates. Something like this.

```py
@app.callback(
    Output('graph-to-update', 'figure'),
    Input('input-slide', 'value')
)
def my_graph_func(var):

    with localconverter(ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
        result = robject(var)
    
    fig = create_myfigure(result)

    return fig
```

The rpy2 documentation explains your problem: https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/pandas.html